# Adding barchart into tooltip of scatterChart in nvd3 - react component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I created a `scatterChart` from `nvd3` and then tried to customize the tooltip the way it is described here:

[nvd3 piechart.js - How to edit the tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416508/nvd3-piechart-js-how-to-edit-the-tooltip)

using `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator()` approach:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import nvd3 from 'nvd3';
var nv = nvd3;
import BarChart from './BarChart';
class ScatterChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.createScatterChart = this.createScatterChart.bind(this);
}

...
...

chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      var html = "<div>";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
              var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>"
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>"
              html += "<p><BarChart datum = " + makeDatumForBarChart(expr) + "/></p>"
          }
        });
      })
      html += "</div>";
      return html;
    })
```

`<BarChart datum = { datum }/>` - tag there is `discreteBarChart` also from `nvd3`. `BarChart` `react` component is not called here (I am setting breakpoints up in that `BarChart.jsx` file) for some reason, so the barchart is not rendered (the tooltip is working fine, except no barchart is drawn). How to make it render?

`BarChart` code looks like that (already fixed): [React: Pass function to a child not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957424/react-pass-function-to-a-child-not-working)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the architecture of the app a bit and ultimately implemented what I needed, but not directly embedding barchart into the tooltip. If anyone knows how to actually do that, please, reply. For now I have barchart appearing on the side at the same time as tooltip appears. Instead of embedding directly, I am just calling a function from `contentGenerator` that updates the state, changing a variable `neuron_name` that is passed into child component `BarChart`, which changes it. Here is the code:

```
var that = this;
    chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      var html = "<div>";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {

          // This function updates the state
              that.showBarChart(elem.key);

              var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";
          }
        });
      })
      html += "</div>";
      return html;
    });
```

Here is the function `showBarChart`:

```
showBarChart(neuron_name) {
    this.setState({
       neuron_name: neuron_name
    })
}
```

Here is what I am having in the `constructor` of the `React` component:

```
class ScatterChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.createScatterChart = this.createScatterChart.bind(this);
     this.showBarChart = this.showBarChart.bind(this);
     this.state = {
         neuron_name: ""
     }
  }
 ...
 ...
```

Finally, the `render`:

```
render() {
  return <div width={500} height={500}>
          <svg ref={node => this.node = node} width={500} height=
{500}></svg>
          <BarChart datum = { 
expressionDatum.getDatumForNeuron(this.state.neuron_name) }/>
        </div>
}
```

And here is a screenshot of what I got. Hovering over a new point shows a new barchart below the scatter chart:

[image]